# Merging scripts without loss of functionality

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can run the following code to add a dynamic formula to a column:

```
function addFormulaSortCol() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FY 19 Tracker");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("U2:U");

  cell.setFormula(
    "=IF(AND(COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),20)))>=1,ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),10)))),DATE(1900,1,1),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),10)))"
  );
}
```

And I can run the following code to sort the records on the same tab:

```
function sortDocs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FY 19 Tracker");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z500");

  // Sorts by the values in column 21 (U)
  range.sort({ column: 21, ascending: true });
}
```

Then I merge the two scripts:

```
function AddColFormulaThenSort() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FY 19 Tracker");

  var cell = sheet.getRange("U2:U");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z500");

  // Adds dynamic formula to every cell in column U
  cell.setFormula(
    "=IF(AND(COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),20)))>=1,ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),10)))),DATE(1900,1,1),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),10)))"
  );

  // Sorts by the values in column 21 (U)
  range.sort({ column: 21, ascending: true });
}
```

This script does execute, but the sorting doesn't happen even after running again. How should the code be updated to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function AddColFormulaThenSort() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("FY 19 Tracker");
  var rg1=sheet.getRange("U2:U");
  var fA=rg1.getFormulas();
  for(var i=0;i<fA.length;i++) {
    fA[i][0]="=IF(AND(COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),20)))>=1,ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),10)))),DATE(1900,1,1),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),10)))";
  }
  rg1.setFormulas(fA)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var rg2=sheet.getRange("A2:Z500");  
  rg2.sort({column: 21, ascending: true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that sort gets called before the formula has a chance to evaluate?

You could try adding a [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) between the `setFormula` part and the `sort` part.